# Auth Proxy for all ingress requests

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, proxy, multi-tenant

We would like to provide a multi tenant application that identifies the tenant based on a subdomain. As authentication server we use Keycloak, in which each tenant has its own realm.

Now we want to authenticate all requests to our application using a auth proxy. If the request is already authenticated (it has a cookie), the request should be forwarded to the backends. If the request is not yet authenticated (it does not have a cookie), the request should be forwarded to Keycloak and to the correct realm based on the subdomain and an oAuth flow should be initiated. After successful login, a cookie should be set so that all subsequent requests are authenticated. This is exactly the functionality offered by [oauth2-proxy](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy). However, we have the further requirement that we have different realms that map the individual tenants. This is not possible with oauth2-proxy at the moment.

Is there another solution besides [oauth2-proxy](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy) that offers this functionality (possibly Nginx or a plugin for it)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**OIDC PLUGIN**

You could use [lua-resty-openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc) with any Lua based Nginx system, eg Kong or OpenResty. This is an established plugin that does the same job as oauth2-proxy. You can have multiple instances of it configured, for different paths, representing different tenants:

```
location /tenant1/ {
    rewrite_by_lua_block {
        var opts = ... 
        local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)
    }
}        
location /tenant2/ {
    rewrite_by_lua_block {
        var opts = ... 
        local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)
    }
}
```

There are also various ways to look at input criteria, such as an `origin` header and re-route accordingly, which can be useful sometimes, though there is a learning curve.

**DESIGN**

I would question your design a little though. Multiple realms effectively means your apps need to deal with multiple authorization servers, which is a complex setup. Eg APIs need to validate multiple types of access token.

If possible, prefer a solution where you use a single authorization server and simply add a tenant ID claim to access tokens, then ensure that APIs deny access to tenant 2 data for users from tenant 1.

This related answer on [multiple realms for a single application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68909371/how-to-authenticate-users-from-different-realms-against-a-single-application) also discusses some trade offs around how data can be accessed.